# What does a large C parameter mean in GridSearchCV?

Tags: parameters, classification, logistic-regression, grid-search, hyperparameters

I'm pretty new to machine learning and its concepts so some clarification would help.

I'm using Logistic Regression to predict binary results (0 or 1). I'm using GridSearchCV to do some hyperparameter tuning to find the optimal `C` and `penalty` parameters.

- Why am I getting such a high C?
- What does a high C signify?

---

Code:

```
# Setup hyperparameter grid
c_space = np.logspace(-5, 8, 15)
param_grid = {'C': c_space, 'penalty': ['l1', 'l2']}

# Instantiate logistic regression classifier
logreg = LogisticRegression()

# Instantiate GridSearchCV
logreg_cv = GridSearchCV(logreg, param_grid, cv=5)

# Fit to data
logreg_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Print the tuned parameters and score
print("Tuned Logistic Regression Parameters:
      {}".format(logreg_cv.best_params_)) 
print("Best score is {}".format(logreg_cv.best_score_))
```

Output:

```
Tuned Logistic Regression Parameters: {'C': 268.26957952797272, 'penalty': 'l2'}
Best score is 0.7974137931034483
```

Comment: As [documented here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression), C is inverse of regularization, the larger the C, the smaller is regularization, means that your algo is more prone to overfit the data.